# Problems with using BibTeX, the simplest code ever is not working

Tags: bibtex

I am completely new at using BibTeX for referring and citations, I used to include the reference list in the tex file everytime. Now I would like to modernise myself i little bit.

As I am totally new at this I read this page:

http://www.bibtex.org/Using/

I followed EXACTLY the steps in there: I created a .bib-file with the following:

```
@misc{ Nobody06,
   author = "Nobody Jr",
   title = "My Article",
   year = "2006" }
```

and then I created the following tex-file:

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage{cite}

\begin{document}

\title{My Article}
\author{Nobody Jr.}
\date{Today}
\maketitle

Blablabla said Nobody ~\cite{Nobody06}.

\bibliography{mybib}{}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\end{document}
```

I generate the pdf and nothing shows up: Just [?] and no reference at the end.

I am wondering, what can go wrong in such simple procedure? Thank you very much for any hints you may have!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! Have you run `bibtex` as well? You need to compile with `pdflatex`, then `bibtex`, then `pdflatex` twice. Edit: See e.g. [Question mark instead of citation number](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/63852)

Comment: I'd be wary of http://www.bibtex.org/: the site is not in any any official and has some poor/bad info. Better by far is  [_Tame the BeaST_](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/bibtex/tamethebeast/ttb_en.pdf).

Comment: Assuming your ran BibTeX you should have a log (`.blg`) file: does it report any errors?

Comment: Aha! Torbjørn was right, I need to compile bibtex first :S now it works, I suppose this has to be done once just at the beginning? Thanks a lot! :D

Comment: Bibtex has to be run everytime you add or delete references. Many good tex editors detect whether bibtex runs are necessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is your output,

[image]

then, most likely, your file `mybib.bib` is not accessible by LaTeX. This means that it is not in the same folder as your LaTex file, or it does not have the `.bib` extension.

Otherwise, there's nothing wrong with your code. It would compile correctly like this:

[image]

Comment: Aha!? Ok, but it is in the same folder and it has the bib extension :(

Comment: Try executing "bibtex mybib" on the command line, and then recompile your latex file with "pdflatex mybib". Try each a few times if needed.

Comment: @mark, better use a TeX editor, e.g., TeXworks, that automatically recompiles and does BibTeX runs when necessary.